# Why is header not visible as soon as I open Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

This is a [web site](https://tiff.net/events/youth-for-change-greta-thunberg-autumn-peltier?fbclid=IwAR33Xvh_tc_Sad9HzNafOLK48Ats2fmMLOs6SaN2KX7LZ542UuJwuEi-qkk) that I can't inspect with [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).
As soon as I open the Devtools the top Header disappear.

Look at the images:

Header visible:
[image]

Header gone:

[image]

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Website uses responsive layout, where header is expected to disappear if screen width is less then a particular value. When you open devtools - viewport becomes more narrow and responsive layout does its job.

Try to open devtools in a separate window with a special button in top right menu of the devtools panel:

[image]

Comment: Click on the 3 dots in the righthand side to change the docktype